# Playwright - how to print element to HTML?

Tags: node.js, playwright

I'm using Playwright with node.js. I've found an element with `page.$$`, how do I save its outer HTML to string?

Comment: $$ is deprecated now.Use locator -https://stackoverflow.com/a/77022191

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have more element handles you got using `page.$$()` and you want to get an outer html of each, this would be a way:

```js
const outerHtmls = await page.$$eval('.myElement', el => el.outerHtml);
```

More information about `page.$$eval()` could be found [here](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#pageevalselector-pagefunction-arg-1).

Comment: So, in other words, Playwright doesn't have an `outerHTML()` function, so just use `$$eval()` (or `evaluate()` or something similar) to call `.outerHtml()` directly on the element in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Playwright doesn't have an `outerHTML()` function. It sounds like you already have an `ElementHandle`. If so, try this!

### Javascript

```
async function outerHtml(elem) {
    if(!elem) {
        return undefined;
    }

    return await elem.evaluate(elem => elem.outerHTML);
}
```

### Typescript

```
async outerHtml(elem: ElementHandle) {
    if(!elem) {
        return undefined;
    }

    //@ts-ignore
    return await elem.evaluate(elem => elem.outerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use locator.

Use of $$ is discouraged per latest playwright [docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-elementhandle).

```
const tweets = page.locator('.tweet .retweets');
expect(await tweets.evaluate(node => node.outerHTML)).toBe('10 retweets');
```